# Referencing an image in theos jailbreak tweak?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I am learning how to do jailbreak dev. Have very basic setup right now that displays an custom alert with an image by overriding the openURL function in an application.

Jailbreak works and the alert shows up. However the image instead the alert does not. I have an image file called `MasterCard@2x.png` in the root folder of the jailbreak (same level as Tweak.xm). My guess is that its not getting packaged in the build and hence when program runs in the iPhone the alert cannot find the image.

```
UIImageView *card1ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mastercard"]];
```

Any ideas how to include and reference the image (or any other resource) correctly in jailbreak app? I am building using `iOSOpenDev` (though also have the tweak working with standard theos make setup)

Comment: I have no idea about jailbreaking but in Objective-C that should be `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mastercard.png"]`

Comment: @Desdenova as the image file is png so in Objective-c both `Mastercard.png` and `Mastercard` works well.

Comment: uhhh. nope! In objective c you can use imageName:@"Mastercard" and then package up the Mastercard.png and Mastercard@2x.png file in your app. IOS decides at runtime which image file will get used depending on the device screen type (@2x on high res devices such as iPhone 4S). Try it out. 
My question still stands...

Comment: Indeed, they changed it after iOS 4 for PNG only. Well good luck on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pathForResource` instead? 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html